# Java interface.class for OIM in C# via IKVM

Tags: c#, java, oracle, interface, ikvm

I used IKVM to convert Oracle's OIMClient libraries to a dll.  Don't want to use java, want to use .NET, but there are no APIs for OIM for .NET.

If anyone has used OIM, what you do is create the OIMClient Object, then you create a UserManger object that it used to find, modify, create, users.

Here's the java code (which is tested and works):

```
UserManager umgr = null;
umgr = oimClient.getService(UserManager.class);
```

In case it is not know, this is the getService method:

```
public virtual object getService(Java.Lang.Class serviceClass);
```

In .net, I can't find a way to use interface.class.
- .class does not exist for the UserManager object in C#.
- If I try to convert it to a java class i get, "cannot convert from 'oracle.iam.identity.usermgmt.api.UserManager' to 'java.lang.Class'"

One other note:  I am wondering if IKVM didnt convert something properly, or I may just be lost :)

So, my question is:  How in C# does one perform the java command *Interface*.class?

Comment: seems to me this should be (somewhat) equivalent to `typeof(UserManager)` which returns a `System.Type`. However the whole java "class" stuff looks like a horrible code smell to me. That should be a generic method, such as `GetService<T>()`, but java is a ridiculous joke and so are java generics, therefore they use this horrible "class" thing instead of proper generics.

Comment: Thanks man,  I havent checked for a response to my question.  Thought I would be notified if I got one, maybe I'm a noob?  I was afraid of your answer, which further confirms to me how bad java really is, always has been...

Comment: good thing *you* said that. Now I have a stronger argument. java is a joke, java generics get deleted when compiling and don't make it to the bytecode, which is just ridiculous. Who wants to write code that doesn't get compiled? java sucks so much I have no words for it. Once again, oracle should create versions of their stuff made in serious languages, not just java.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm trying the same thing and not even getting this far (OIMClient.login() fails).

Comment: I did not.  I gave up.  Felt like I was the only one in the world trying to accomplish this.  My partner at work and I suspect that when one tries to login, there is some form of token that is not coming back from oim.  I tried so many different things, started to think that the ikvm could not convert the all the libraries to dlls.  Oracle blows, giant piece of unmanageable bloatware with half-assed support that costs way too much money.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by HighCore in his comment, 'typeof(UserManager)' is what you want. As in

```
umgr = (UserManager)oimClient.getService(typeof(UserManager));
```

Any method that wants a Java class can be provided with a .NET Type. You can see this by looking at the metadata for java.lang.Class and noting that it provides an implicit cast to SystemType.

```
[Serializable]
[Signature("T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Serializable;Ljava/lang/reflect/GenericDeclaration;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;")]
public sealed class Class : Object, Serializable.__Interface, GenericDeclaration, Type, AnnotatedElement, ISerializable
{
    // <SNIP>
    public static implicit operator Class(global::System.Type type);
}
```